# Examples of android applications that use direct database access instead of content providers?

Tags: android, database, android-contentprovider

Just found out that I don't need content providers if I don't need to share data with other applications.  But since the examples I've seen all use content providers, I'm not sure how to proceed without them and populate activities with data derived from accessing my application's database directly.

Comment: Where is your application's database? on the same device or remote database accessible via internet/intranet?

Answer (score 2):

The [Notepad Tutorial in the Android Developer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) shows how to access a SQLite database "directly".

Comment: You're right.  Was aware of the tutorial but thought it was the same implementation as the one included with the SDK (which uses ContentProvider)  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [LunchList application](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials) built up in [Android Programming Tutorials](http://commonsware.com/AndTutorials) does not use a `ContentProvider` (particularly look at tutorial #11). Neither does [this sample app](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Database/).

Comment: Checked it out.  Great resource.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLiteDatabse example for this because if you don't want to use Content Provider.but Sqlitedatabase is private and not accessible to another Application.

so you can refers 
following link:http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/